# Spark: Distributed, incremental model training?

Tags: apache-spark

Looking for a distributed, incremental model training in Spark. For example:

- A model_1 is trained to classify web text.
- Model_1 is saved to a file system.
- New texts are classified. Human experts very classification results and select texts that were correctly classified.
- Model_2 is trained using old model_1 and selected, correctly classified texts on previous step.

Can this be done with Spark MLLib? Other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Spark you can't incrementally retrain or add examples to the training set.
After expert classify you can create a new dataset (with old + new examples) and retrain the model from the beginning.

You can also create an ensemble with old + new model and weigh them accordingly

As far as I know (I hope someone proves me wrong) there isn't any framework that provides incremental learning out-of-the-box. So you need to implement an incremental mechanism by yourself. In most simple cases ensemble is a weighted sum of the prediction of a set of models.

Example: You have two binary classifiers that return two probabilities and predictions.

`(probability of negative; probability of positive) => prediction`

- The first classifier:  `(0.40; 0.60) => 1`
- The second classifier: `(0.30; 0.70) => 1`

suppose your ensemble weights both models with equal weights, `0.5`

- The ensemble of both classifiers: `(0.35; 0.65) => 1`

where:
`probability of negative = probability of negative of the first model * weight of first model + probability of negative of the second model * weight of the second model`

Comment: Other frameworks where incremental training can be done? How to create ensemble with old + new model and weight them ? Thanks!

Comment: As I understand, in the case you describe above you have two models: 1) model_1  trained on data_set_1 and 2) model_2 trained on (data_set_1 + new_data). Thus model_2 is a brand new model, created independently from model_1 with more data. There is no incremental model training here, we start training all over again from state zero, and we are not reusing existing model_1. Correct?

Comment: It depends on your data. If your expert label substantial subset of data you can create model on only new data, if not, you can retrain model with old + new data